# Expo Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND assets, while making IOS Archive

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, expo

I want to make a production build in IOS, So I just deleted my Derived data and clean the project. Then I run `expo publish` after publishing was completed I started to make an Archive. At last I got Error like

```
[20:20:20] Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND assets
[20:20:20] Before making a release build, make sure you have run 'expo publish' at least once. Learn more. (​https://expo.fyi/release-builds-with-expo-updates​)
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
```

I tried all the way but no use, tell me how to resolve this issue.